# Setting a variable name with another variable value - Java Script

Tags: javascript, variables, naming

I want to get a value from a variable then use that as the name for another variable. I got something like this:

```
var eval(BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseTitle"]) = BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"];
```

This is giving me an error, 'missing ; before statement'.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't make dynamic variable names in javascript. What are you trying to achieve so that we can help you with a solution to your larger problem?

Comment: Sure you can.  Variables are properties, and dynamic property names can be used with square bracket property syntax.

Comment: @Jon: Global variables are properties of `window` in web browsers, but not necessarily elsewhere. Local variables aren't properties.

Comment: @outis I could be mistaken, but they are properties of the enclosing object (functions or otherwise).

Comment: Basically I need to associate variables in a meaningful way. Right now I have an object array but no way to get variables from it except from the index. I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: @Jon: nope. Try `var thing={act: function() {var foo="bar"; return this.foo;} };   thing.act();`. The result is `undefined`, not `"foo"`.

Comment: @Jon: local variables might have been properties of functions in some implementations of JS 1.1 (I scarcely remember anymore), but it never made it into the standards.

Comment: @outis, @Jon: Internally, variables are properties of the *variable object*. In *global code*, the variable object is the global object itself, in *function code* the variable object is the *activation object*, which is not reachable. More info: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3 and http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.2

Comment: @CMS, @outis, Yes, I was mistaken, the variables are associated with the execution context, not the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `eval` will give you a form of variable variables, it's messy and potentially leads to syntax errors:

```
try {
    eval('var ' + BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseTitle"] + ' = BodyWeight[i].ExerciseVideo');
} catch () {
    // what to do here if BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseTitle"] isn't a valid variabe name?
}
```

Better to use object properties rather than local variables.

```
thing[BodyWeight[i].ExerciseTitle] = BodyWeight[i].ExerciseVideo;
```

Comment: This is what I got so far:
 eval('var ' + BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseTitle"] + ' = ' + BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"]);

Except it's giving me an error 'unexpected end of XML entity'. Any ideas =/ ?

Comment: That's basically the syntax problem I mentioned. The difference between your code and mine is significant. In this case, `eval` leads you down a dark path. Use object properties instead.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier if you specify the part you currently have enclosed in `eval` as a property.

```
var myvar = {};
myvar[BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseTitle"]] = BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"];
```

No evil eval necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are hoping to accomplish:

```
var eval(BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseTitle"]) = BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"]; 

//to try and get
var BodyWeight4ExerciseTitle = BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"];
              ^-//guessing this is an iterator
```

To accomplish this, just do:

```
var key = 'BodyWeight' + i + 'ExerciseTitle';
window[key] = BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"];

//now you have a global variable "BodyWeight4ExerciseTitle"
```

Comment: Actually, I modified this into this:
var key = BodyWeight[i]['ExerciseTitle'];
window[key] = BodyWeight[i]["ExerciseVideo"];

And it worked! So thanks!

Comment: Except that globals are evil (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad, http://www.google.com/search?q=globals+are+evil). Unless you have a compelling reason to use globals (which I don't see for this problem), use local variables or object properties instead.

Comment: @outis - true... I wasn't sure how the OP needed this variable so sticking it in the window was a simple option... but it could just have easily been stuck in another object.